# Java with JPanel

Tags: java, arraylist, jpanel

I'm building a form in which the user can enter in employee info and display it in a textarea field but I also have a display all or "see all" button that I cant get to work. \

I am saving each submission saved into an array called `resultshold` and then that array is saved into an array called `line` but both arrays only hold one submission instead of multiple - I tested it and each time I display the contents of the array 'line' it just shows the last submission meaning its not storing mutiple submission each time the calculate button is clicked - Ive added a counter to the line array to set the position of the store "text" variable but it only saves one and not mutiple- can someone help or guide me in the right direction - below is my code.

```
public class Container extends JFrame {
    ArrayList<String> resultsHold = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList line = new ArrayList<>();
    //private String[] resultsHold;
    private final JLabel EmployeeNamelabel;
    private final JLabel HoursWorkedLabel;
    private final JLabel department;
    private final JLabel emptycell;
    private final JLabel wageLabel;
    private final JLabel departmentresultsLabel;
    private final JTextField EmployeeNameTexfield;
    private final JTextField HoursWorkedtextfield;
    private final JTextField wagetextfield;
    private final JTextArea resultsscreen;
    public JButton seeAll;
    public JButton myExitButton;
    public JButton CalcButton;
    public JButton ClearButton;
    JPanel centerPanel;
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JPanel textfieldPanel;
    JPanel myresultsPanel;

    public Container() {
        super("Payroll Program");
        String[] departments = {"CHOICE 1", "CHOICE 2", "CHOICE 3",
                "CHOICE 4", "CHOICE      5", "CHOICE 6"};
        final JComboBox<String> departmentsV = new JComboBox<String>(departments);

        departmentsV.setVisible(true);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 5, 8, 8));

        //creating text fields, labels and buttons

        emptycell = new JLabel("");
        departmentresultsLabel = new JLabel();
        EmployeeNamelabel = new JLabel("First Name");
        HoursWorkedLabel = new JLabel("Hours Worked");
        wageLabel = new JLabel("Wage");
        department = new JLabel("Department");
        EmployeeNameTexfield = new JTextField(5);
        HoursWorkedtextfield = new JTextField(5);
        wagetextfield = new JTextField(5);
        resultsscreen = new JTextArea(20, 50);
        myExitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        myExitButton.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        CalcButton = new JButton("Calc");
        CalcButton.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        ClearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        ClearButton.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        seeAll = new JButton("See All Results");
        seeAll.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));

        //adding labels
        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        textfieldPanel = new JPanel();
        myresultsPanel = new JPanel();

        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 8, 8));
        centerPanel.add(EmployeeNamelabel);
        centerPanel.add(HoursWorkedLabel);
        centerPanel.add(wageLabel);
        centerPanel.add(department);

        // adding text fields
        textfieldPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 8, 8));
        textfieldPanel.add(EmployeeNameTexfield);
        textfieldPanel.add(HoursWorkedtextfield);
        textfieldPanel.add(wagetextfield);
        textfieldPanel.add(departmentsV);

        //adding the buttons to the panel
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 8, 8));
        buttonPanel.add(seeAll);
        buttonPanel.add(myExitButton);
        buttonPanel.add(CalcButton);
        buttonPanel.add(ClearButton);
        myresultsPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 8, 8));
        myresultsPanel.add(emptycell);
        myresultsPanel.add(resultsscreen);
        myresultsPanel.add(emptycell);
        myresultsPanel.add(emptycell);

        getContentPane().add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(textfieldPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(myresultsPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //clear button action event listener

        ClearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                EmployeeNameTexfield.setText("");
                wagetextfield.setText("");
                HoursWorkedtextfield.setText("");
                resultsscreen.setText("");
            }
        });

        //end clear listener
        CalcButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            private int counter;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String mymy[];
                counter++;
                String hoursC;
                String name;
                Double total;
                String wageC;
                name = EmployeeNameTexfield.getText();
                wageC = wagetextfield.getText();
                hoursC = HoursWorkedtextfield.getText();
                total = Double.parseDouble(hoursC) * Double.parseDouble(wageC);
                departmentresultsLabel.setText((String) departmentsV.getSelectedItem());
                String text = name + "'s" + " weekly pay is: $" + total + "..." + "Department:      " + departmentsV.getSelectedItem();
                //  resultsscreen.append(
                // name +"'s"+" weekly pay is: $" + total + "..." + "Department:                      "+departmentsV.getSelectedItem());
                resultsHold = new ArrayList<>();
                resultsHold.add(text);
                //resultsHold.set(counter,text);
                // line= new ArrayList<>();
                line.add(counter, resultsHold);
                // System.out.println(line.size());
                // if(resultsHold.size()>0){
                System.out.println(resultsHold.size());
                resultsscreen.append(resultsHold.toString());
                // }
                System.out.println(counter);
                EmployeeNameTexfield.setText("");
                wagetextfield.setText("");
                HoursWorkedtextfield.setText("");
                resultsscreen.setText("");
                //resultsHold.add(name);
                //resultsHold.add(wageC);
                // resultsHold.add(hoursC);
                // resultsHold.add(total.toString());
                // resultsHold.add((String) departmentsV.getSelectedItem());
                //line.set(i, resultsHold.get(i));
                // line.add(resultsHold);
                //  System.out.println(line);
                resultsscreen.append(line.toString());
            }
        });
        //event listeners
        myExitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //exit program
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        seeAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); i++) {
                    resultsscreen.append(line.get(i).toString());
                    System.out.println(line.get(i));
                    //System.out.println(line.size());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Container guiwindow = new Container();
        guiwindow.ShowWindow();
    }

    public void ShowWindow() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 300);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zhuinden Formatting is ok, but please don't remove other changes

Comment: @msrd0 that's the problem with parallel edits that don't get merged

Comment: Your arraylist called `line` is missing the template parameter and you're using a raw type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
resultsHold = new ArrayList<>();
resultsHold.add(text);
```

So, every time your button is clicked, you're recreating a new list and store the text inside. You don't want to create a new list. You only want to add something to the already existing list.

Note that your code is really awful: public fields, use of raw types, code commented out, Java conventions not respected at all, meaningless variable names...

Comment: This did the trick and sorry guys for the sloppy code, I was going to clean it up once I get it to work, I apologize for that. JB many thanks brother! Your instructions got the program to work - I cant believe I was so stupid to miss that.

Comment: re: your comment - In my experience, writing code sloppily to "clean up later" is a bad idea in general.  After you have it working, there are several strong forces against you "cleaning it up later" -- changes are liable to break things; the code was poorly organized and now needs redesign, not just cleaning; if you need help, the poorly written code makes it harder for someone else to help you, and harder for you to find your own problems.  Good code from the first is faster to write once you factor in rewriting, testing, problems, etc.